# How to merge data into a central SQL Server database via E-Mail with a WinForms C# application?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, ms-access-2003

I have an old Access database (`.mdb`/2003) that was used as application for the sales representatives team.

Problem:

My task is now to write a WinForms application that every sales representative will in future have on his laptop. All data that each of them are collecting must then be updated afterwards to a central db in the company. The Access database must be migrated to SQL Server.

I was first thinking of a web application, but this option is not allowed or otherwise possible.

Is there a way that each sales representative stores his data on a local db on his laptop, and then sends his db via E-Mail, In the end the data of all sales representatives must be merged together into the central database. Any idea, that follows this concept -> store data locally and send it via E-Mail, to fill the central database?

Regards and thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Well I guess [you can use SMTP to synchronise data...](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947057)

Comment: This question is better suited to Programmers.SE since it does not involve specific code, but rather architectural issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not such a big deal to write a c# application to store data in xml format, maybe zip and encrypt it, attach it to an email and then send it to a specific address (for example using .net [SmptClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

the bigger task will be to write a service on server side to wait for incoming emails and write attached data to sql server ...

Comment: I think XML is a way to go. Thank you all so far for your input!